# A particular integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\prod_{k=-n}^{n}(x-k)}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

I have to show summability, then compute the following integral:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(\pi\,x)}{\prod_{k = - n}^n (x - k)}\,dx = \frac{(-4)^n}{(2\,n)!}\,\pi $$

for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Is it possible to avoid the residue theorem?

I would be happy with a real-analytic solution, if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Done.  Now what?

Comment: Oh, do you have a question about the problem you have posed?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: search for  a simple expression for the dominator based on x powers. i know there exist , but i cant remember exactly what it was

Comment: It is an interesting problem, so I am quite against closing votes, but the OP should be aware that the current policy of MSE is to explain the attempts made to solve the proposed problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A possible approach is the following: for first, prove that:

$$\frac{1}{\prod_{k=-n}^{n}(x-k)}=\frac{1}{(2n)!}\sum_{h=0}^{2n}(-1)^h \binom{2n}{h}\frac{1}{x-n+h}\tag{1}$$
through the residue theorem or partial fraction decomposition, then recall that:
$$ \forall m\in\mathbb{Z},\qquad \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-m}\,dx = (-1)^m \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x}\,dx = \pi(-1)^m \tag{2}$$
and at last, combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ to prove your claim:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\prod_{k=-n}^{n}(x-k)}\,dx = \frac{\pi (-1)^n}{(2n)!}\sum_{h=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{h} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi(-4)^n}{(2n)!}}.\tag{3}$$

Notice that by $(1)$ and $(2)$, summability is granted due to the (Riemann-)summability of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, that follows from integration by parts or the Dirichlet's criterion.

Comment: I was able to develop Equation $(1)$ but curious as to whether there is a more elegant and efficient approach than my "brute force" way, which gave me a head ache at the 3rd step.  Not tough, just boring and tedious.

Comment: @Dr.MV: I think that the efficient way is to consider the residues of the LHS at $x=-n,\ldots,n$. But we may prove $(1)$ also by induction on $n$, it is not difficult or terribly long.

Comment: Yes, I was calculating residues for $n=1$, $n=2$, $n=3$, to see if a pattern emerged.  It did.  And once having it, induction confirms validity.  I was wondering if there is a more elegant way.  How did you arrive at $(1)$?

Comment: @Dr.MV: $$\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{\prod_{k=-n}^{n}(x-k)},x=0\right)=\frac{(-1)^{2n}}{n!^2}=\frac{1}{(2n)!}\binom{2n}{n},$$ and the other residues are similar.